# Simple Bash If statement

Tags: bash

I'm trying to code a simple test for a directory, but keep running into a problem I've been unable to solve.

```
 prompt> if [ -d "./mydir" ] then echo "yes"; fi
 -bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'
```

I've tried a variety of quotes, semi-colons, line-breaks, etc.
But always run into this syntax error.

Can you explain what I've done wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a semicolon to separate the condition command and the `then` keyword:

```
if [ -d dir ]; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
# ...........^
```

You can of course use a newline instead of the semicolon

Or, use a conditional operator

```
[ -d dir ] && echo yes
```